# Are there any ways to update off-chain metadata attributes or property of a solana metaplex nft through api calls?

Tags: amazon-s3, solana, nft, metaplex

I know there is a specific instruction pre-written on metaplex package that allow us to update on-chain metadata of a NFT, but I couldn't find or figure out a way to update off-chain data through api call from either frontend or backend.

I believe this can be done through a service like AWS S3, but I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve this goal

Questions:

So, 1) I want to ask is there a better method to update off-chain data through AWS S3 bucket, and 2) If so, could you explain how? 3) If not, could you explain how can I update json file on S3 Bucket through api calls from my frontend or backend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Off-chain metadata is not part of the Solana Network so there are not any function/command that allow you to change data inside a offchain object.

What are your options?

1. You can change the onchain pointer to the offchain link to another ([Metadata account has an `uri` field](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/accounts#metadata) inside the onchain data that you can change to any other `uri` [using metaboss](https://metaboss.rs/update.html#update-uri) for example). This is the normal option if you are using an storage like [Arweave](https://www.arweave.org), because arweave stored files are unmutables.
2. If you are using something like S3, the way to update the offchain data is creating a backend that allow you to interact with ur AWS storage and change the data that you want. This will affect the NFT that has the onchain pointer to that offchain file, so you dont have to run any onchain update, just need to create a backend system that allow you to interact with ur AWS files.

Comment: Hey! Thank for answering my question :) Btw, do you know where I can find resources or documentations about api specifications required to do such operations with AWS S3. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have Dynamic Metadata you can check out Cardinal.io as Well. [Link](https://github.com/cardinal-labs/cardinal-generator)